# c# fahrenheit and celsius: adding input to answer

Tags: c#, .net

I have written some c# code for a small program (fahrenheit to celsius and Vice Versa), but I would like to add the number of the input to the answer.

I would like the result to read/show: 178 degrees fahrenheit is 81 celsius degrees.

Code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FahrentheitTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //conversion from Fahrenheit to Celsius
            Console.WriteLine("Input temperature value to view Fahrenheit to  Celsius: ");
            int fah = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();

            //conservsion formula from F to C
            int FtoC = ((fah - 32) * 5) / 9;
            Console.WriteLine("Degrees Fahrenheit is {0} Celsius degrees. ", FtoC);
            Console.WriteLine();

            //conversion from Celsius to fahrenheit
            Console.WriteLine("Input temperature value to view Celsius to Fahrenheit: ");
            int cel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();

            //conversion formula from C to F
            int CtoF = ((cel * 9) /5) + 32;
            Console.WriteLine("Degrees Celsius is {0} degrees Fahrenheit. ", CtoF);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obligatory comment about rounding due to integer division.

Comment: @AdamV: Obligatory retort that if you multiply and then divide it's probably close enough for the purpose if you don't need to display decimals. Only downside is you get truncation instead of rounding.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your format string to include two format values, one for the input and one for the result:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} Degrees Fahrenheit is {1} Celsius degrees. ", fah, FtoC);

Console.WriteLine("{0} Degrees Celsius is {1} degrees Fahrenheit. ", cel, CtoF);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to already have figured out how to print a string with one formatting placeholder:

```
Console.WriteLine("a is equal to {0}.", a);
```

You can extend it to two by just adding another placeholder and variable like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("a is equal to {0} and b is equal to {1}.", a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you almost got it.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} Degrees Fahrenheit is {1} Celsius degrees.", fah, FtoC);
```

Wouldn't you just also have the input variable into the same Console.WriteLine, but as the first parameter?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FahrentheitTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //conversion from Fahrenheit to Celsius
        Console.WriteLine("Input temperature value to view Fahrenheit to  Celsius: ");
        int fah = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();

        //conservsion formula from F to C
        int FtoC = ((fah - 32) * 5) / 9;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Degrees Fahrenheit is {1} Celsius degrees. ", fah, FtoC);
        Console.WriteLine();

        //conversion from Celsius to fahrenheit
        Console.WriteLine("Input temperature value to view Celsius to Fahrenheit: ");
        int cel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();

        //conversion formula from C to F
        int CtoF = ((cel * 9) /5) + 32;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Degrees Celsius is {1} degrees Fahrenheit. " , cel, CtoF);
           Console.WriteLine();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest learning how to encapsulate your rules/logic right off the bat.

Your "immediate need" answer is in the ToString implementation.

```
namespace Weather
{
    using System;

    public class CeliusToFahrentheit
    {

        public int? Celius { get; set; }
        public int? Fahrentheit
        {
            get
            {
                int? returnValue = null;

                if (this.Celius.HasValue)
                {
                    returnValue = ((this.Celius * 9) / 5) + 32;
                }

                return returnValue;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string returnValue = string.Empty;

            if (this.Celius.HasValue)
            {
                returnValue = string.Format("{0} degrees celsius is {1} fahrenheit degrees.", this.Celius.Value, this.Fahrentheit.Value);
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

and calling code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {

            CeliusToFahrentheit ctf = new CeliusToFahrentheit();
            ctf.Celius = 100;
            Console.WriteLine(ctf.Fahrentheit);
            string mesg = ctf.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(mesg);
```